# Save a php variable when a link is clicked

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$raw_results = 

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE (`idStudent` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`FirstName` LIKE '%".$query."%')"); 
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
{
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{ 

echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'>

 <td height='25px'><a href ='editRegistration.php'> "
 .$results['idStudent']."</td> <td>".$results['FirstName']."</td>






</tr>" ;
}
```

What I want is to store the value of clickable link in to a php variable, so I could send it to aother page. How do I do that? Thank you

Comment: Is there another way? I don't know ajax too well

Comment: it depends where you want to use your variable. Maybe use a hidden field?

Comment: The other page is editRegistration.php? The link value is $results['idStudent']?

Comment: One thing you could do is [move away from those darn mysql_ functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and then read up on SQL security [1](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) [2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet) [3](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may reform the link printing as:

```
"<a href ='editRegistration.php?id=".$results['idStudent']."'> ".$results['idStudent']."</a>" ;
```

This will send you to the editResgistration.php with "id"-GET value. In your editRegistration.php you can get the value by:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set whatever you like as query parameter sin a link.  I.e.

```
echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'>
  <td height='25px'><a href ='editRegistration.php?id=" . $results['idStudent'] . "'>"
    . $results['idStudent'] . "
  </td>
  <td>".$results['FirstName']."</td>
</tr>" ;
```

THen your editRegistration.php can read the student's ID from `$_GET['id']`.

(This assumes your ids are numbers or similar and do not need url encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You can put it this way. And in `editRegistration.php` page, use `$ _GET ['id']`

```
echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor='#0f7ea3'>
  <td height='25px'>
    <a href ='editRegistration.php?id=" . $results['idStudent'] . "'>"
    . $results['idStudent'] . "
  </td>
  <td>".$results['FirstName']."</td>
</tr>" ;
```

> editRegistration.php

```
$_GET['id'];
```